Flask app sign in error with google oauth - DEBUG: https://www.googleapis.com:443 "GET /oauth2/v3/certs HTTP/11" 200 744
Everytime i try to sign in with google on my website i get 'DEBUG: https://www.googleapis.com:443 "GET /oauth2/v3/certs HTTP/11" 200 744'. then leads me to 'Not Found' page.
I've tried debugging all i can in my app.py but everytime i click continue with google then click on my google account to sign in, it leads to a 'Not Found. The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.' page. I checked the logs on cpanel for my flask app and saw: 'DEBUG: https://www.googleapis.com:443 "GET /oauth2/v3/certs HTTP/11" 200 744'.
Not too sure what this exactly means or how to fix it.
here is a snippet from my app.py:
@app.route("/google-login")
def googleLogin():
    redirect_uri = url_for("googleCallback", _external=True)
    print("Redirect URI:", redirect_uri)
    return oauth.myApp.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)
    

@app.route("/signin-google")
def googleCallback():
  token = oauth.myApp.authorize_access_token()
  userinfo = token.get('userinfo', {})

  # info from json of google
  email = userinfo.get('email')
  given_name = userinfo.get('given_name')
  family_name = userinfo.get('family_name')
  sub_token = userinfo.get('sub')  
  picture_url = userinfo.get('picture')

  existing_user = db.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE sub_token = ?", sub_token)

  if not existing_user:
    try:
    
      db.execute("INSERT INTO users (email_address, given_name, family_name, sub_token, picture_url) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", email, given_name, family_name, sub_token, picture_url)
      print("User added to the database.")
    except Exception as e:
      print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

  session["user_id"] = token
  return redirect(url_for("home"))

also towards the top of my app.py i have this:
appConf = {
    "OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID": "my client id",
    "OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET": "my client secret",
    "OAUTH2_META_URL": "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    "FLASK_SECRET": "my key",
}

app.secret_key = appConf.get("FLASK_SECRET")
oauth = OAuth(app)

oauth.register("myApp",
               client_id=appConf.get("OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID"),
               client_secret=appConf.get("OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET"),
               server_metadata_url=appConf.get("OAUTH2_META_URL"),
               client_kwargs= {
                   "scope": "openid profile email"
               }
               )

Maybe i misconfigured it for production? I'd appreciate the help a ton, thank you.
I tried contacting cpanel support, google documentation review, changing or reconfiguring my app.py.
